# Is Parallel.For capable of handling Exceptions?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

In my current project I am using Parallel.For loop instead of normal For loop. My question is If one iteration is failed in the Parallel.For loop, is it capable of handling the exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** based on [akton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1634846/akton)'s comments.

No, `Parrellel.For` does not handle exceptions. You should handle the exceptions yourself.

For a brief explanation look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460695.aspx)

Comment: I think the answer is "No `Parrellel.For` does not handle exceptions. You should handle the exceptions yourself". Veeresh is asking whether he has to handle them himself when changing to `Parrallel.For` within the lambda expression, which you do. It is what Azodious meant but not what he said.